# C++ WinAPI: HWND To String Returning Hex

Tags: c++, string, winapi, converters, hwnd

I am using WinAPI and im trying to make a program which allows you to change the title.

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)

#define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
#define UNICODE
#endif
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string HWNDToString(HWND inputA);
void setTitle(string inputA);

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("CodeBlocksWindowsApp");
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;

    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,128,0));

    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl)) return 0;

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx
    (
        0,
        szClassName,
        _T("Title Changer"),
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        400 + 22,
        400 + 49,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        hThisInstance,
        NULL
    );

    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    return messages.wParam;
}

HWND textout, titlebutton , powerbutton, textin;
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            textout = CreateWindow("STATIC", "Enter new window title here:", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 0, 0, 230, 20, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            textin = CreateWindow("EDIT", "New Title", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 0, 20, 250, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL);
            titlebutton = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Set as New Window Title", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 0, 45, 210, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) /*=*/1/*=*/, NULL, NULL);
            powerbutton = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Power Off", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 316, 0, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);
        break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1)
            {
                SetWindowText(hwnd, HWNDToString(textin).c_str());
                MessageBox(hwnd, string("Title changed to: " + HWNDToString(textin)).c_str(), "Title Changed", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            }

            if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2)
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

string HWNDToString(HWND inputA)
{
    stringstream stringstreamBuffer;
    stringstreamBuffer << inputA;
    return stringstreamBuffer.str();
}
```

But the program sets the title to a random hex-like string (for example, `0x123abc`).

What is wrong with the `HWNDToString` function I defined? Do I need to use `sprintf` to convert hex to string?

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64
IDE: Codeblocks
Compiler: GNU GCC Compiler (MinGW32)

Comment: `HWNDToString` is returning you the window handle as a string. What is it you expect it to do? If you want the **title** of the window you need to use `GetWindowText()` to read it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm trying to get the contents of `textin` and convert it to string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `HWND` is a pointer (`struct HWND__*` or `void*`, depending on whether [`STRICT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383732.aspx) is enabled or disabled, respectively). Passing such a pointer to `operator<<` of an `std::ostream`-based class will invoke `operator<<(const void*)` which formats the pointed-to memory address as a hex string.

Since you are trying to accept a string value from the user using an `EDIT` control and then set your main window's title with the value of that string, you should be using the [`GetWindowTextLength()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633521.aspx) and [`GetWindowText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx) functions instead:

```
string HWNDToString(HWND inputA)
{
    string s;
    int len = GetWindowTextLength(inputA);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        s.resize(len + 1);
        len = GetWindowText(inputA, &s[0], s.size());
        s.resize(len);
    }
    return s;
}
```

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1)
    {
        string s = HWNDToString(textin);
        SetWindowText(hwnd, s.c_str());
        MessageBox(hwnd, string("Title changed to: " + s).c_str(), "Title Changed", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    ...
```

On a side note, your "Power Off" button should be sending a `WM_CLOSE` message to your main window, not calling `PostQuitMessage()` directly:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        ...
        case WM_COMMAND:
            ....
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2)
            {
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            }
            break;

        // By default, DefWindowProc() handles WM_CLOSE by destroying the window
        // using DestroyWindow(). WM_CLOSE is also received when the user closes
        // the window manually. This allows you to close down your app correctly
        // regardless of how the window is closed.  You can handle WM_CLOSE
        // manually if you want to prompt the user before allowing the
        // window to be destroyed...
        /*
        case WM_CLOSE:
            if (MessageBox(hwnd, "Are you sure you want to power down?", "Power Down?", MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        */

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See MSDN's documentation on [Destroying a Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598.aspx#destroying_win) for more details.

Comment: In case I were to use HWND to String conversion elsewhere, I would like do be able to do it without having to read the window title. I am now using `DestroyWindow(hwnd)` for the power off button and everything closes at once neatly, thank you.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 `In case I were to use HWND to String conversion elsewhere, I would like do be able to do it without having to read the window title.` The original code you posted *did* convert the HWND to a string (representation of its pointer value). But apparently what you meant is the contents of the `EDIT` control, which is what `GetWindowText` in the answer above returns.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 Calling `GetWindowText()` on an `EDIT` control retrieves its content, not its title (it does not have one). A title is retrieved only if you call `GetWindowText()` on a top-level window that has a title. This is clearly stated in the `GetWindowText()` documentation: "*Copies the text of the specified window's title bar (if it has one) into a buffer. If the specified window is a control, the text of the control is copied.*"

Comment: I think I should have made my self more clear. I want the code to set the window title to what I specified in the `textin` textbox, and display the contents of `textin` in the message box, without having to rely on getting the contents of the windows title. All I need to do to solve my problem is to figure out how to get the data the hex string returned from `HWNDToString` points to.

Comment: The answer has been given to you, to do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 your intention was clear from the beginning. The code I gave you in my answer does EXACTLY what you are asking for. It gets the text entered in the `textin` control, sets it as the title of the main window, and displays it in a message box. Did you even TRY the code yet? Do you understand what the code DOES and HOW it works? Stop focusing on the hex string, you are focusing on the wrong thing, and ignoring everything else that actually matters.

Comment: Really sorry everyone, I tried out the code for a simple pass the text in a second text box to a second sentence in the message box. It worked. However, the conversion seems to cut off the last character. `New Title` becomes `New Titl`.

Comment: I solved that problem too: `int len = GetWindowTextLength(inputA) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumble upon this question, here is a very simple function to do that:

```
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

string HWNDToString(HWND input)
{
    string output = "";
    size_t sizeTBuffer = GetWindowTextLength(input) + 1;

    if(sizeTBuffer > 0)
    {
        output.resize(sizeTBuffer);
        sizeTBuffer = GetWindowText(input, &output[0], sizeTBuffer);
        output.resize(sizeTBuffer);
    }

    return output;
}
```